# In Rebase some of my commits are getting loss, How to rebase correctly?

Tags: git, github

I have checked out `feature_branch` from `common_branch` from commit `c2`, and make changes with commits `c12`, `c13`, `c14`. and `common_branch` has new changes `c3` and `c4`.

Now the `common_branch` looks like: `c1==> c2 ==> c3 ==> c4`. And `feature_branch` look like  `c1 ==> c2 ==> c12 ==> c13 ==> c14`.

When I try to rebase I lose few of my commits like: `c12` and `c13`, but have `c14`.

I have run the following commands

```
git checkout feature_branch
git rebase common_branch
```

Comment: Do you have to rebase? I think a simple merge no-ff should do the trick

Comment: If `feature_branch` has some commits that have the same changes with some on `common_branch`, these commits will be dropped. Besides, merge commits are also dropped by default.

Comment: Don't worry, you have not lost any commit. Simply run `git reflog` and you'll find your commits. What you've done is the correct way to rebase. Note that rebasing will create a simple but yet different commits. Why do you think you've lost your commits?

Answer (score 0):

First, lets clear something up. After you rebase `feature_branch`, it no longer contains commit `c14` as you think. Rather it contains a **new** commit with the same textual changes as `c14`. Let's call this new commit `c14'` ("c14 prime"). This is a new commit because it has a different parent, among other things.

Most likely you no longer see the commit messages from `c12` and `c13` is because the changes from these commits are already present in other commits. I suggest that you look at the files that were changed on these two commits and verify that those changes are present after you rebase.